# How to path through the changeable address in folder name

Tags: batch-file

How to path through the address %known_path%\folder_name-[%CHANGEABLE_PART%] \ there.exe ?

Source

`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\OneDrive\Applications\blender-2.78.0-git.1bd6ed7-windows64\blender -R`

to something like that

`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\OneDrive\Applications\blender*\blender -R`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you know the name of the executable, why not retrieve the changeable directory name, then append the required suffix.

```bat
For /D %%A In ("%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\Applications\blender-*") Do Start "" "%%A\blender.exe" -R
```

---

Or directly retrieve the executables full path:

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where /F /R "%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\Applications" "blender.exe"') Do Start "" %%A -R
```

Comment: oh god, I would never have done it by myself, works perfectly! (the second one is faster ;) —  thank you very much Compo!